# "Binning" items in an ObservableCollection into separate ListBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I've recently encountered a rather severe performance issue with how I'm "binning" items in my ObservableCollection into individual ListBoxes.  This works in its current iteration and my issue arises when the user wants to zoom in/out on the timeline.

The zooming changes the amount of time each block on the timeline represents and will potentially require moving some elements in one ListBox into an adjacent ListBox.  It also will occasionally require the addition or removal of ListBoxes.

I'm guessing the issue may be in how I go about reshuffling the entries in the OnZoomChanged method.  The other issue is that all of the entries appear to be redrawn each time one is added.  Both of these can pair up for making a decent big of lag during the update process (adding/zooming).  When I'm upwards of around 50-60 entries I really start to notice the performance hit on zooming.

My ultimate goal here is to be able to sort entries that would be overlapping with each other into separate bins (StackPanel/ListBox etc) and allow the user to still be able to browse through all of them if they so desire.  The entries are a fixed size (which is what creates the overlapping issue).

Thanks for any insights/suggestions!

Here's a breakdown of how everything is setup:

**The View** - granted this is a simplified version of the control.  The DateTime (GroupingTime) is used in my custom view for placement on the timeline (and this works).  Then the list of timeline entries (GroupEntries) is fed into the TimelineEntryControl to appropriately draw the entry in the ListBox.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TimelineEntries}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Views:CustomView>
        <ListBox>
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <Controls:TimelineEntryControl TimelineEntry="{Binding}" Height="50" Width="50" Margin="0,0,0,12"/>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
      </Views:CustomView>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**The ViewModel** - TimelineEntryViewModel

```
internal class TimelineEntryViewModel : ViewModel, IDisposable
{
  private readonly ObservableList<TimelineEntry> _groupEntries = new ObservableList<TimelineEntry>();
  private readonly ObservableCollectionHandler<TimelineEntry> _groupEntriesHandler;

  public TimelineEntryViewModel( TimelineViewModel timelineViewModel )
  {
    Tvm = timelineViewModel;
    _groupEntriesHandler = new ObservableCollectionHandler<TimelineEntry>(_groupEntries, OnAdded, OnRemoved);
    GroupEntries = _groupEntries.CreateView();
    GroupEntries.SortDescriptions.Add( new SortDescription( "TimeOccured", ListSortDirection.Ascending) );
  }

  private void OnAdded( TimelineEntry tle )
  {
    GroupEntries.Refresh();
  }

  private void OnRemoved( TimelineEntry tle )
  {
    GroupEntries.Refresh();
  }

  public void AddEntry( TimelineEntry tle )
  {
    _groupEntries.Add( tle );
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    _groupEntriesHandler.Dispose();
  }

  public TimelineViewModel Tvm {get; private set;}
  public DateTime GroupingTime {get; set;}
  public ICollectionView GroupEntries {get; private set;}
}
```

**The TimelineViewModel** - the parts that govern the handling of the entries/zoom.  I use an eventAggregator to respond to specific messages that contain the information that goes into these entries and respond by creating the entry the calling the AddEntry function to place it in the appropriate location in the View.

```
internal sealed class TimelineViewModel : ViewModel, IDisposable
{
  private readonly ObservableList<TimelineEntryViewModel> _timelineEntries = new ObservableList<TimelineEntryViewModel>();
  private readonly ObservableHandler _timelineEntriesHandler;

  public TimelineViewModel ( )
  {
    // Omitting unnecessary code here
    _timelineEntriesHandler = new ObservableHandler( _timelineEntries );
    TimelineEntries = _timelineEntries.CreateView();
    TimelineEntries.SortDescription.Add( new SortDescription( "GroupingTime", ListSortDirection.Ascending ) );
    TimelineEntries.Refresh();
  }

  private void AddEntry( TimelineEntry tle )
  {
    var timeForNoOverlap = Projection.UnprojectDuration( 90 ); //This just gets the number of pixels needed for no overlap between panel groups.
    if( _timelineEntries.Count == 0 )
    {
      _timelineEntries.Add( new TimelineEntryViewModel( this ) );
      _timelineEntries[0].GroupingTime = tle.TimeOccured;
      _timelineEntries[0].AddEntry( tle );
    }
    else if ( tle.TimeOccured > _timelineEntries.Last().GroupingTime + timeForNoOverlap )
    {
      _timelineEntries.Add( new TimeLineViewModel( this );
      _timelineEntries.Last().GroupingTime = tle.TimeOccured;
      _timelineEntries.Last().AddEntry( tle );
    }
    else
    {
      foreach( TimelineEntryViewModel tevm in _timelineEntries )
      {
        if( tle.TimeOccured >= tevm.GroupingTime && tle.TimeOccured <= tevm.GroupingTime + timeForNoOverlap)
        {
          tevm.AddEntry( tle );
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    TimelineEntries.Refresh();
  }

  private void OnZoomChanged()
  {
    var tempEntries = new ObservableList<TimelineEntryViewModel>( _timelineEntries );

    foreach( var group in _timelineEntries )
      group.Dispose();
    _timelineEntries.Clear();

    foreach( var group in tempEntries )
    {
      foreach( var item in group.GroupEntries )
        AddEntry( (TimelineEntry)item );
    }

    foreach( var group in tempEntries )
      group.Dispose();
    tempEntries.Clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: binning? shouldn´t be binding?

Comment: It's binning in the sense that I have this collection of objects with a time they occured.  I want to place them on the timeline with respect to that (and I can do that already)  But if they overlap I want to put them into a scrollable UIElement to prevent the overlap.  Hence the 'binning'.

Comment: I know this may not be the best suggestion, but it seems like what you want here is a custom panel that gives space only to certain children and not others. I've made one before, and it is fairly straight forward, and will teach you a lot about the wpf layout process. You can also use it to optimize or virtualize. A good place to start is by looking at wpf's implementation of stackpanel or grid, both of which are freely available for reference. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rscc/archive/2008/10/22/wpf-sources-for-net-framework-3-5-sp1-are-available.aspx